# How to retrieve Custom Keys or Custom Data (Push Notification Payload) from Push Notification response?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-ios

I am using Salesforce Marketing Cloud SDK and MCCordova Plugin. I tried accessing userInfo dictionary data as mentioned in below link, But I am not receiving any Push Notification payload data.

https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/push-notifications/custom-keys.html

Comment: For the record; are you receiving the push notification?  Trying to discern if you are getting the message and simply can't get to the raw data or are you not receiving the notification at all?

Comment: I am receiving notification. Notification Data values contains alert, title, sound, type and some metadata. But I am not receiving Custom Keys configured in Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

Comment: Please share the code snippets from which you expect to get the keys.

Comment: Thanks Bill.. It's not an issue in accessing Custom Keys. It's an issue with Marketing Cloud Journey configuration. After creating new Journey, I started receiving Custom Keys